# Visual Studio Intellisense works in Class Library but not Web Project files

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

I'm not sure how this happened as up until this morning my Intellisense was working fine in Visual Studio.

Now, however, I have lost Intellisense in my web project's files. Also, I don't see the little toolbar at the top of the window that allows me to select objects and controls

i.e. This one:
[image]

I did notice however that Intellisense and the controls selection toolbar works in my class library.

Any idea how to fix this?
I've read somewhere about setting the Build Action of my web project files to "Compile", but I cannot find a BuildAction property anywhere.

Comment: Click into text editor, press F4 key and then the property windows should be visible. In the property window should be "BuildAction" property.

Comment: Tried that - only properties are File Name and Full Path.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your web project, Select "Property Pages"(Shift+F4) and Click on "Build" You will see a check box "Build Web site as part of the solution". Make sure that is checked. I would also check if there are any projects that are not loaded in your solution and also restart VS and try loading the solution once again. See if you still face this issue.